# Windows Azure and GoDaddy problem

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, azure

I am having a problem getting my CNAME and A records right.

Assumptions:

- **Azure Name** : MyApplication.cloudapp.net
- **GoDaddy DomainName** : MyDomain.com

I want both `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` to go to the same place. What is happening is that only `www.mydomain.com` works and whenever I use `mydomain.com` it doesn't work on Chrome (but it works fine in Firefox).

I have added a CNAME record like this:

```
Host = www                
PointsTo = MyApplication.cloudapp.net
```

As we all know Azure IP address change so I couldn't use the A (Host) record, instead I can only use CNAME (Alias).

Any thoughts on this, I am sure this is a common problem with Azure and GoDaddy (or other hosts)?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?  What behavior are you observing?

Comment: I get this on Chrome :

Oops! Google Chrome could not find MyDomain.com

Answer (score 2):

Your IP address in Windows Azure remains the same unless you delete the contents of the deployment. Some hosts allow you to set the root record to a CNAME, whereas others will allow you to automatically redirect. I've not had any experience with GoDaddy so can't help there.

Please see [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simondavies/archive/2010/03/01/how-does-ip-address-allocation-work-for-compute-services-in-windows-azure.aspx) about IP lifetime.